# How to kill my process? Without killing process which belong another users

Tags: c#, com, process

I have an Excel application which doesn't close.
This my code

```
    xlApp = new Excel.Application();
    Workbooks = xlApp.Workbooks;
    xlWorkBook = Workbooks.Open(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
    xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
--------------------------------------------------------
    xlWorkBook.Close(false);
    xlApp.Quit();
```

And now a try to kill Excel process like this:

```
Process[] exProc = Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL");
foreach (Process proc in exProc)
{
   proc.Kill();
}
```

But I don't know how to kill process, which I started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to release you Excel COM object for it to close properly

```
Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet);
xlWorkBook.Close(false);
Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);
xlApp.Quit();
Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlApp)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are creating a process, try to keep it's handle in a variable, like use CreateProcess API which will return HANDLE to process you've created, using that HANDLE, you always can get process ID using GetProcessID API.